# Shortest way to access VARCHAR by index

Tags: sql

In C/++/#/Java/everything I would just `my_str[desired_index]` and that's all.
But in SQL (at least Oracle) the only way I've found so far:

```
SUBSTR( my_str, desired_index, 1)
```

But it's so awkward, I can't believe in 2011 I have to do this.

Is there other way?

Comment: I think your in the wrong job if you think that is awkward.

Comment: @Ash heh ) maybe, maybe. But really, how is it better at any level then C syntax ?

Comment: If you are using `SUBSTR` frequently would it not be better to extract the character to it's own field in your table when the data is inserted? Then you can query it directly and avoid all this awkwardness ;)

Comment: @Tony No, it would not be better to denormalize your data without a very good reason to do so. It would usually be better to use a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the standard way to do it in SQL.  Some DBMS have a dialect of SQL that supports an alternative notation; for example, Informix supports `my_str[desired_index]` (and, for a three-character substring, `my_str[12,14]` where both values are offsets).

The question is - why do you need to write that in SQL?

Comment: 'why do you need to write that in SQL?' - in check constraint, I want to validate some positions

Comment: Informix syntax seems very nice, especially substring

Comment: @Alexander: If you're checking fixed positions, do you really need CHAR(n) instead of VARCHAR(n)?  It also means you are using a more complex data type implemented as a [VAR]CHAR...this isn't wrong, but it tends to make the management trickier.  Are you sure you don't need a number of separate CHAR(1) fields instead?

Comment: ehh, can't remember recent, more complex use cases, but in my current task I need to validate just 1st character, so it has to be VARCHAR. This case is not really important, but time after time index access would make my code simpler to understand and I just don't understand why such a basic thing is so verbose. And I just hoped that I missed smth.